# Use setAttribute in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, getelementbyid, setattribute

I'm new in using phonegap and I have some problems.

I've created a webbased application which is running pretty nice in the browser (also on android).
Now I want to port it to a phonegap-application.
It was a little bit tricky to get the mainpage running - there are only a few lines of javascript, but it works.

At this time I've just one input on the mainpage, just a textinput. I found to change the value by using:

```
$('#input').val('Value');
```

But now i want to set some other attributes. In javascript i used:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.setAttribute("value", "Value");
input.setAttribute("name", "Name");
input.setAttribute("myOwnAttribute", "Something");
```

When I try this in phonegap I'll get the error

```
Object #<HTMLDocument> has not method 'getElementById'
```

If I try

```
$('#input').setAttribute("value", "Value");
```

I'll get the error

```
Object has not method 'setAttribute'
```

So why is this not working?
How can I set any attribute of any object?

Thanks a lot

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the attr function.

```
$('#input').attr("value", "Value");
$('#input').attr("name", "Name");
$('#input').attr("myOwnAttribute", "Something");
```